# How to use multiple isblank statements inside an if statement

Tags: excel, if-statement

Is it possible to use multiple isblank statments in an if statement. I want to use something like this sudocode

```
=if(isblank(g8)&isblank(h8), "both blank", "not both blank")
=if(isblank(g8&h8), "both blank", "not both blank")
```

These function return the $VALUE error or return the wrong text int the if statement.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: For future reference basic `IF` statement questions are better suited to Super User

Comment: that said with a small tweak your second formula results in a shorter result `=IF(LEN(G8&H8)=0, "both blank", "not both blank")`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
=if(AND(isblank(g8),isblank(h8)), "both blank", "not both blank")
```

Comment: I assume this can be expanded for more than two as well as be incoorporated in a large nested if/else loop?

Comment: In Excel2007 and up, `AND()` can take up to 255 arguments.  It can be nested/combined just like any other function.

Answer (score 2):

If your ranges are contiguous, using the following formula will take as many arguments as you want, with a much easier syntax to type when you expand the range:

`=if(counta(g8:h8)=0, "both blank", "not both blank")`